# Incorrect component display when passing props and using Tailwind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-functional-component

I pass the color data to the created component to set a specific color in several places. At the output, it turns out that it is installed only in one place. What could it be? In the project I use only tailwind.

```
<div className="w-full flex justify-between items-center gap-5">
   <FilterButtons dataFilter={""} flag="Artists" color="yellowColor" />
   <FilterButtons dataFilter={""} flag="Albums" color="orangeColor" />
</div>

<div className="w-full flex justify-between items-center gap-5">
   <FilterButtons dataFilter={filterByCategory} flag="Category" color="orangeColor" />
   <FilterButtons dataFilter={filterByLanguage} flag="Language" color="yellowColor" />
</div>
```

[Broadcast props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2dSy.png)

```
const FilterButtons = ({ dataFilter, flag, color }) => {

return (
    <div className={`w-1/2 flex items-center justify-between px-4 py-2 border border-${color} text-${color} rounded-xl  cursor-pointer`}>
        <p className={`tracking-1 text-lg`}>{flag}</p>
        <MdOutlineKeyboardArrowDown className={`text-4xl`} />
    </div>
)
```

}

[Usage in the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrnFw.png)

The first block displays a field with a yellow border with black text and with orange texts and a white border

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlPqh.png)

I tried to divide into different variables and set conditions with different flags, nothing changes

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take it into account. Added code to the question

Comment: You should tag the question or at least include what library you’re using to style the components.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having some css specificity issue which is very common with tailwind. But tailwind has a workaround for this.

Use exclamation on the class you want to force a higher specificity for. Example (in your case):
`!text-${color}`

Comment: it didn't help. it just removes the style and puts black everywhere (